# Deferring signal handling in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to figure out how to block a signal in Linux kernel 2.4 (user space) from invoking its handler, but keep it available to be handled later, preferably as soon as I re activate the handling of said signal.

The function sigprocmask seem to come up in all my search results, but I can't find a good, clear description that explains whether the blocked signal gets "saved" to be handled later, and if so where and how do I handle it when I'm ready for it.

Can someone please clarify what's going on, preferably with a code example? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really can't say it better than the `signal(7)` man page:

> A  signal  may be *blocked*, which
>   means that it will not be delivered
>   until it is later unblocked.  Between
>   the time when it is generated and when
>   it is delivered a signal is said to be
>   *pending*.
>
> Each thread in a process has an
>   independent signal mask, which
>   indicates the set of signals that the 
>   thread  is  currently blocking.  A
>   thread can manipulate its signal mask
>   using `pthread_sigmask(3)`.  In a
>   traditional single-threaded
>   application, `sigprocmask(2)` can be
>   used to manipulate the signal mask.

So, you can block and unblock the signal with `sigprocmask()`.  If the signal is raised while it's blocked, the handler won't be called until it's unblocked.  If a signal is pending when it's unblocked, the handler for the signal will be called as usual.

Note that a given signal is either pending or not; it can't be "pending twice" (or more).  if the signal is raised twice while it is blocked, it'll still only be delivered once.